# Real example of Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Please give me real example of emberjs. This example will help me understand how to write in emberjs.

**Description of example:**

Please open this link first:
http://jsfiddle.net/kwladyka/KhQvu/2/
(this is prototype to better understand what i am talking about)

**And then read:**

Emberjs download `Groups.owner` by JSON from `json.php?name=groups-owner&user_id=58` and `Groups.member` from `json.php?name=groups-member&user_id=58`. Both in `Groups.all`.

In object Groups i have all values of arrays what i read from JSON. I want example read something like that: `owner[2][name]`.

Then from `CreateGroupsSelect` i want read `Groups.all` and create ListBox with values `group_id` and names `name`. And when i change select i want change `<p>You select {{name}} with id {{id}}</p>` and refresh data in other View emberjs objects.

I will be really gratefull for help. I am trying learn emberjs but i totally block with this example.

---

Ok, so i have many questions :)

1)
[How to bind value form input select to attribute in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531820/how-to-bind-value-form-input-select-to-attribute-in-controller)

```
var val = $('select option:selected').val();
```

Where can i find list of possible ussage like a "select option:selected". Any documentatin for that? Where?

2)
"didInsertElement"
How can i know i should use this? How should i looking in documentation to know that? Why not Ember.Select.Change for that?

3)
Why author use "View", i thought for select i should use class "select"?

4)
Seriously this is my first language when i fill all is so random and i dont have any idea how to know what i can write and where. I fill really stupid with that. Any hint how to understand that?

5)
Ok so step by step...

First of all i want read JSON and prepare data to use.

```
Organizer.Groups = Ember.Object.extend({
    owner: [],
    member: [],
    all: function(){
        var owner = this.get('owner');
        var member = this.get('member');
        return owner.concat(member);
    }.property('owner', 'member'),

});
```

a) "Object" is good choice for that?

b) I want fill "owner" by array from "json.php?name=groups-owner&user_id=58". How to do that? Did i define "owner" corretly or i should write "ArrayController" or something else for that? Mayby just "Array" or "ArrayProxy"? I am filling so confuse now.

c) How should i initiate load data from JSON? I want do this only one time on the beginning.

PS Sorry if you fill my questions are so stupid but i really dont know answers and i dont hide this :)

Comment: This is not a question... You should isolate your actual problem and ask in a technical-fashion why would this happen and eventually how to fix it. No offense, but I feel that your post belongs more to google groups to be asked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to work with select menu in Ember js

[select dropdown with ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911206/select-dropdown-with-ember)

Here is an example of working with routes and outlet helper

[Right way to do navigation with Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318572/right-way-to-do-navigation-with-ember)

If you use routing make sure you have ember latest, routing is still not released.

[Router / StateManager - can't make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386176/router-statemanager-cant-make-it-work/11390348#11390348)

When using latest emberjs refer to documentation in source code, the documentation in ember site will be for present stable release.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js

The links to routing is provided from your fidle title "Router with dynamic routes"

It will be hard to solve your complete problem, give it a try starting with the routing example from above, when you are stuck ask more specific questions, we'll be happy to help.

EDIT : Some of the links are already outdated.